# ¿Cómo hago para VACIAR o borrar todos los Elementos de una Lista Enlazada Simple? JAVA

Tags: java, lista, excepciones, nullpointerexception, nodos

```
//CLASE NODO  

package Nodo;

public class Nodo {
    private int dato;
    private Nodo SiguienteNodo;

    public Nodo(int Entrada) {
        dato = Entrada;
        SiguienteNodo = null;

    }

    public void EnlazarNodo(Nodo NuevoNodo) {
        SiguienteNodo = NuevoNodo;
    }

    public int ObtenerDato() {
        return dato;
    }

    public Nodo ObtenerSiguienteNodo() {
        return SiguienteNodo;
    }

    public void setDato(int dato) {
        this.dato = dato;
    }
}

//FIN CLASE NODO

//CLASE LISTA
package Lista;
import Nodo.Nodo;

public class Lista {
    Nodo cabeza;
    int tamaño=0;
    
    public Lista () {
        cabeza = null;
        tamaño=0;
    }
    
    public void Agreagar_A_Cabeza (int nuevoelemento){   
        if (cabeza==null){
           Nodo temp = new Nodo (nuevoelemento);
           cabeza = temp;
        }
        else {
            Nodo temp = new Nodo (nuevoelemento);
            temp.EnlazarNodo(cabeza);
            cabeza = temp;
        }
        tamaño++;
    }
    
    public int MostrarElemento (int index) {
        Nodo temporal = cabeza;
        for (int i = 0; i <index; i++) {
            temporal = temporal.ObtenerSiguienteNodo();
        }
        return  temporal.ObtenerDato();
    }
    
    public void EliminarDato (int index) {
        if (index==0) {
          cabeza = cabeza.ObtenerSiguienteNodo();
        }
        else {
            Nodo NodoTemporal = cabeza;
            for (int i = 0; i <(index-1); i++) {
                NodoTemporal = NodoTemporal.ObtenerSiguienteNodo(); 
                // si yo tengo esta lista -> 5  6  4  2    
                //El programa me va ir de numero en numero hasta que llegue antes
                //del numero que desee borrar, se lo salta y lo enlaza a los demas.
                // -> 5  6  |4|  2   ->  5  6  2  se salto el numero 4 y enlazo el 6 con el 2     
            }
            NodoTemporal.EnlazarNodo(NodoTemporal.ObtenerSiguienteNodo().ObtenerSiguienteNodo());
        }
    }

    public void VaciarLista () {
        Nodo temp = cabeza;
        for (int i = 0; i <tamaño; i++) {
            temp =  temp.ObtenerSiguienteNodo();
            temp.setDato(0);
        }
    }
}

//FIN DE LA CLASE LISTA

//CLASE PRINCIPAL
package Main;

import Lista.Lista;

public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Lista list = new Lista ();
        
        list.Agreagar_A_Cabeza(4);
        list.Agreagar_A_Cabeza(3);
        list.Agreagar_A_Cabeza(2);
        list.Agreagar_A_Cabeza(1);
        
        System.out.println("Lista: ");
        System.out.print(list.MostrarElemento(0)+", ");
        System.out.print(list.MostrarElemento(1)+", ");
        System.out.print(list.MostrarElemento(2)+", ");
        System.out.print(list.MostrarElemento(3)+" ");
        System.out.println("");
        
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Se ha borrado el 1 Elemento");
        System.out.println("");
        
        System.out.println("Nueva Lista: ");
        
        list.EliminarDato(0);
        
        System.out.print(list.MostrarElemento(0)+", ");
        System.out.print(list.MostrarElemento(1)+", ");
        System.out.print(list.MostrarElemento(2)+" ");
        System.out.println("");
        
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Lista vacia: ");

        list.VaciarLista();     
        System.out.print(list.MostrarElemento(0)+", ");
        System.out.print(list.MostrarElemento(1)+", ");
        System.out.print(list.MostrarElemento(2)+", ");
        System.out.print(list.MostrarElemento(3)+" ");
        System.out.println("");
    }
}

//CLASE PRINCIPAL
```

Por favor revisen el método *VaciarLista*, la verdad no se como se vacía la lista, formule esa lógica. Me funciona pero me muestra en pantalla lo siguiente:

> ```
> run:
> Lista: 
> 1, 2, 3, 4 
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> Se ha borrado el 1 Elemento
>
> Nueva Lista: 
> 2, 3, 4 
>
> Lista vacia: 
>   at Lista.Lista.VaciarLista(Lista.java:91)
>   at Main.Principal.main(Principal.java:44)
> C:\Users\Miguel Angel\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
> BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

primeramente con vaciar lista a que te refieres, si es que todos tengan el valor 0 este seria el código, recuerda que en el main solo tienes que mostrar la cantidad de datos que tienes aniadidos(en este caso se puede mostrar los que tiene el valor de 0)

```
    public void VaciarLista_Todos0(){
    Nodo temp = cabeza;
    for(int i =1 ; i<= tamaño;i++){
        temp.setDato(0);
        temp = temp.ObtenerSiguienteNodo();
    }
```

Caso contrario seria simplemente seria de que

```
    public void VaciarLista_Vacio(){
    cabeza=null;
}
```

(En tu metodo "EliminarDato()" te falta descontar el tamanio)

Comment: Hola Spider-Man, gracias por el detalle de descontar el tamaño en EliminarDato, probé las dos opciones que me diste, me funciono, pero con el mismo error. Así que le puse un try catch y problema solucionado. Espero que leas este mensaje. Gracias por ayudarme <3